# Run `yarn remove <dependency_name>` to remove dependency, but yarn.lock still shows the removed dependency

Tags: node.js, nestjs, yarnpkg

In my node.js project, I had using yarn installed the dependency `@nestjs/jwt`, now I want to uninstall it since I am not using it.

I run `yarn remove @nestjs/jwt`. It was successful. I checked my `package.json`, it was removed. But when I check the `yarn.lock` file, it is still showing.  Why is that?

My `git add -p yarn.lock` shows me:

```
-"@nestjs/jwt@8.0.0", "@nestjs/jwt@^8.0.0":
+"@nestjs/jwt@^8.0.0":
   version "8.0.0"
   resolved "https://registry.yarnpkg.com/@nestjs/jwt/-/jwt-8.0.0.tgz#6c811c17634252dd1qcd5dabf409db4692b812da"
   integrity sha512-fz2LQgYY2zmuD8S+8UE215anwKyXlnB/1FwJMLVR47clNfMeFMK8WCxmn6xd0hF5JKuV1crO6FVabb1qWzDxqQ==
```

Comment: Another package you've installed may need it. What does`yarn why @nestjs/jwt -R` say?

Comment: Yarn always updates the lock file, so I'd agree with @lossleader here.  Some other package is probably using it.

Comment: You probably had "@nestjs/jwt@8.0.0" in your package.json which yarn has removed (both from package file and lock file). There is some other dependency (of dependency...) of yours that wants "@nestjs/jwt@^8.0.0". So its resolution is still kept in yarn.lock.

Answer (score 2):

Besides packages you explicitly install, packages depend on other packages. To see a graph of any dependents of this package you have installed, do:

`yarn why @nestjs/jwt -R`

Answer (score -1):

Yarn.lock is what yarn uses to know what versions of each dependency are installed so it can get those exact versions again when you run yarn install on a new machine. Try running 'yarn upgrade'. This should create a new yarn.lock file without those dependencies.

Comment: also: this link might help you understand what 'yarn upgrade' does if you are unfamiliar https://classic.yarnpkg.com/lang/en/docs/cli/upgrade/

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This answer is incorrect.  If you check the documentation, it says:  "Note: yarn remove will always update your package.json and yarn.lock. This ensures that different developers on the same project get the same set of dependencies. It is not possible to disable this behavior."